# DB Design Suggestions Location and Sub Location

Tags: mysql, database

I am designing a MYSQL DB that supports a POS functionality. Let says there is a business with multiple locations(Multiple Branch Offices) and each location has to be identified Uniquely but in a hierarchy with its own Taxes, Products, product Groups and Product Sub Groups, Customers and etc..

There needs to be one Primary Location and the others as Sub Locations.

Which is the best way to store this information in a transactional DB? Should I use one table to store both Primary and Sub Location and just use a `Self Join` to retrieve the hierarchy?

Example:

```
StoreID
Sub_StoreID
Store_Name
```

The `Sub_StoreID` will be blank for the primary locations and for others it will store an `ID`.

or should I choose two tables and mentioned below. Should I replicate all the tables for Products? Customer and others to make it work in a better way.

```
Primary_Location_Attributes,
Secondary_Location_Attributes,
Association_Primary_Secondary_locations
```

Let me know if the question is not clear so I can try to explain in a different way.

Comment: By _location_ you mean _branch offices_?

Comment: Yes, Branch Offices..

Comment: I'm guessing the `business` (=primary location) entity would have different attributes than the branch offices (=secondary locations), so I'd go with the two tables model. The association is not necessary as a third table though, a simple FK will do, since the relation is 1:N. Unless I'm missing something, that is.

Comment: So you suggest that I maintain all the other aspects of the business such as Products, Customers etc..in two tables each, one referring to the Primary Location and the other referring to the Branch Offices?

Comment: No, I'm suggesting that `business` would have attributes that are _global to the business_ such as i.e. the brand name. Also, `branch` would have a i.e. `belong_to_business` attribute that `business` hasn't. So `business` and `branch` would have _different attributes_, thus the different tables to host them. Start with that. `customer` and `product` are different entities, and they belong to a "next chapter".

Answer (score 1):

no need in another table, you can make a `parent_id` attribute:

```
CREATE TABLE offices(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    parent_id INT REFERENCES offices(id),
    ...    
);
```

that would be a parent or head office:

```
INSERT INTO offices (parent_id) VALUES(NULL);
```

that would be a suboffice:

```
INSERT INTO offices (parent_id) VALUES(1);
```